# Access wikicode from an xml file in c++

Tags: c++, xml, wiki-markup

I have to read wikidumps and extract the headings, bold words, italics, etc. The formatting is done in wikicode. How can I read the wiki markup? I am using pugiXML to parse the document but I have no idea how to read the wiki markup and extract the text. How can I do this?

Comment: can you show some code of what you've tried and didn't work?

Comment: I don't have the code for this criteria yet. I want to achieve this using regex but haven't been able to do it. Can you guide me a bit on this?

Comment: I have made the following regex:

Comment: \'.*([a-z]|[A-Z])+.*\' But it only returns me the entire string. However, I want to extract each word of the string. How can I do that?

Comment: you need to show the example (representative) text you want to split with the regex - otherwise it might be hard

Comment: my text is the xml file of simple wikipedia.